# Do anyone in the Lord of the Rings or the Hobbit movies mention the existence of Eru the creator, Melkor or other Valar?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Everyone in the *Lord of the Rings* movies is afraid of the One Ring and Sauron so much; are they aware of the greater gods?

Comment: This is a little tricky: Are you asking whether Gandalf, say, is *aware* of Eru in the films? (Answer: yes) Or are you asking whether anyone *mentions* being aware of Eru?

Comment: I believe Jackson was contractually obliged *not* to use any Silmarillion material, so you'd be restricted to any mention of Eru/Melkor/Valar in the LotR books, which is powerful few if any.

Comment: I mean anyone in the movies.

Answer (score 2):

"A Balrog of Morgoth"

Melkor/Morgoth is mentioned by Legolas in *Fellowship* in Lothlórien, after Celeborn asks where Gandalf is, for he would much desire to speak with him.

Comment: Galadriel also calls Sauron a 'servant of Morgoth' in Battle of the Five Armies.